# Bluemix Error deploying node.js app buildpack

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, buildpack, package.json

So I am trying to get this application deployed and here are the logs I have searched the internet and there is not much help for this. Here are the logs

```
2015-10-20T10:15:53.17-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 1928479c-5e79-47bc-a8e0-1bc7d7fb34b1 ({"name"=>"braincar", "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack"})
2015-10-20T10:17:46.30-0400 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid 1928479c-5e79-47bc-a8e0-1bc7d7fb34b1 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2015-10-20T10:17:5 [DEA/101]             OUT Got staging request for app with id 1928479c-5e79-47bc-a8e0-1bc7g43q
2015-10-20T10:17:59.47-0400 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid 1928479c-5e79-47bc-a8e0-1bc7d7fb34b1 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2015-10-20T10:17:59.61-0400 [STG/101]    OUT -----> Downloaded app package (32K)
2015-10-20T10:17:59.72-0400 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/nodejs-buildpack'...
2015-10-20T10:18:01.23-0400 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
2015-10-20T10:18:01.28-0400 [STG/0]      ERR Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
2015-10-20T10:18:02.39-0400 [STG/0]      OUT Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out 'ce9345a9a6e7b00266194cadd18fdwqfe4q'
2015-10-20T10:18:02.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -------> Buildpack version 1.5.0
2015-10-20T10:18:02.50-0400 [STG/0]      ERR cat: /tmp/staged/app/package.json: No such file or directory
2015-10-20T10:18:02.51-0400 [STG/0]      ERR  !     Unable to parse package.json
2015-10-20T10:18:02.51-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Build failed
2015-10-20T10:18:02.51-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
2015-10-20T10:18:02.51-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
2015-10-20T10:18:02.52-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
2015-10-20T10:18:02.52-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        https://help.heroku.com/
2015-10-20T10:18:02.52-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Love,
2015-10-20T10:18:02.52-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Heroku
2015-10-20T10:18:02.52-0400 [STG/0]      OUT Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
2015-10-20T10:18:02.86-0400 [API/2]      ERR encountered error: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

So now what should I do to get this to load I have tried running this command...

```
 cf push braincar -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack
```

the logs above are the results what do I do please help! Thank you!

Comment: do you have a package.json for your app?

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, the application has a missing *package.json* file.

```
ERR cat: /tmp/staged/app/package.json: No such file or directory
2015-10-20T10:18:02.51-0400 [STG/0]      ERR  !     Unable to parse package.json
```

This is necessary to configure and run your application. Can you make sure you've run *npm init* in the project directory?

Comment: When I try to run the _npm init_ it says the command is not recognized. I tried _cf npm init_ and still didn't work. Also what does this command do. I do have a package.json file as well and it is located in the directory.

Comment: Okay, if you have a valid package.json you don't need to run the npm command. Can you verify your JSON file is valid? 
http://jsonlint.com/
Is it possible to post your package.json file into here so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

I recently cam across this problem. In my case, the cause was that within the bluemix deploy task the input was empty (which seems to be the default and doesn't give any warnings). Although the project was correctly set up and a build was running sucesfully before hand, when it came to deploy, it wasn't actually trying to push anything.  Simply setting the input to build artefacts resolved this and the app deployed as expected.

Running a cf push from command line succeeded, which indicated the problem was with the pipeline, not the project.